# Dropdown doesn't work after modal of Bootstrap imported

Tags: javascript, webpack, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I have a header with dropdown-menu. If I click, I will see the menu. All work perfectly. Here is the HTML:
[image]

Another page I had import modal from bootstrap and nothing happens when I click on the dropdown. In the console it doesn't show any errors, but I don't know why, I have 2 events:
[image]

If I remove my import from Js. file, it will work perfectly:

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
```

**app.js**

```
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle');
```

**contact.js**

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
if (document.getElementById('emailHasBeenSent') !== null && document.getElementById('emailHasBeenSent').value) {
    const modal = new Modal(document.getElementById('contactUsModal')),
        closeModalBtn = document.querySelector('.contact--modal-close-btn');

    modal.show();

    closeModalBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        modal.hide();
    })
}});
```

Modal of Bootstrap seems to "cancel" onClick event dropdown. The class name stay on "btn dropdown-toggle" and not "btn dropdown-toggle **show**". Could  you help me to find where is the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Importing straight from 'bootstrap' causes the dropdown listeners to disappear.

Fixed it by using deeper import:
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';

Goes to category: I dont know why but it works.

Comment: I've been struggling so long to even find that this was the issue... very helpful workaround!

Comment: You just saved my day, dude, I've been struggling with this issue for hours!

Comment: programmer who has been staring at this too long note: It HAS to be `import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';`. `import { Modal } from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';` fails.

Comment: I'm loathe to jump in with a "me, too" comment, but I've been fighting this for hours, I thought it was related to jQuery and I was hacking this way and that.  This should be in the bootstrap documentation, it's incredible that importing a modal the documented way would break dropdowns.  Thanks!!

Comment: THANKS! I've spent hours trying to find why TWO of my pages won't work. After boiling it down to the import, it did not look good. But finding this post saved the day :-) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Man! Never thought I would get accurate answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem.
I had loaded bootstrap twice inside another file that comes from xmlHttpRequest.
may by you had a same mistake

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).